# Order by most searched words in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, search-engine

I've designed a simple website which enables users to search on a MYSQL database. The search method is also simple: the user types a word in a textfield and it searches in the database.
Now i want to include in this website a table with the most searched words and i didn't find anything until now but this sentence:

```
select distinct column
       , count(1) as total
    from dept
group by column
order by total desc
   limit 5
```

but this doesnt retrieve what i want. Do you have any idea of how I get this result?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: "i didn't find anything until now but this sentence:" I can barely understand your question.  Whats the table holding the search values?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example for a small site:

After each search, add a row to a table `searched`.  Bonus points for adding a timestamp.

```
insert into searched (keyword, timestamp) values ('foo', 1234567890);
```

From there:

```
select keyword, count(*) as total from searched
  group by keyword order by total desc limit 5;
```

Of course, for simple things like this, I'd use redis.